# Uncaught TypeError: MicrosoftGraph.MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, msal.js

I am revisiting an old side project which I last updated about 1.5 years ago (at this time it was working without errors).

From memory, I believe I used [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript) at the time to create the basic foundation for the app.

On loading the app now I am getting this error in Chrome dev tools:

> Uncaught TypeError: MicrosoftGraph.MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions is not a constructor
> at graph.js:1

The code at line 1 of `graph.js` is:

```
const authProviderOptions = new MicrosoftGraph.MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(scopes);
```

Googling for the error above doesn't *seem* to lead to relevant results.

Below are the various parts of the app I think are relevant in troubleshooting the error.

For reference, it *seems* the the version of MSAL I am using needs to be 'upgraded' from [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-core) (`https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.3.0/js/msal.js`) to [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) (`https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.18.0/js/msal-browser.min.js`), however I haven't tried that yet in case it causes additional issues I do not yet know how to resolve.

**index.html**

```html
        <!-- msal -->
        <!-- from:  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-core -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/lib/1.3.0/js/msal.js" integrity="sha384-xeOjp8/l8VazdeNFRbrC9LWPR1InyrS8E1Na/0lv6V2r09iwX6vJC47FXlczokMi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
        <!-- javascript sdk -->
        <!-- from:  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/graph-js-sdk.js"></script>
  
  
        <!-- the logic of the app's functionality proceeds in the order below -->
  
        <!-- set up click handlers etc -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.js"></script>
  
        <!-- define the configuration for msal -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
  
        <!-- define authentication logic -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/auth.js"></script>
  
        <!-- set up graph client and make api requests -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/graph.js"></script>
</body>
```

**config.js**

```js
// check if running locally and set redirect uri accordingly  
var hostname = location.hostname; 
if (hostname === "localhost" || hostname === "127.0.0.1") {
  console.log("running on localhost"); 
  var redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080"; 
}
else {
  console.log("not running on localhost");
  var redirect_uri = "https://somedomain.com";
}

// msal options
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        // this is the client/application id visible at:
        // https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps
        clientId: "*******",
        // this is the directory/tenant id visible at:
        // https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/Overview/appId/client-id-is-here/isMSAApp/
        redirectUri: redirect_uri,
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/*******"
    },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    forceRefresh: false
  }
  // ,
  //   system: {
  //        logger: new Msal.Logger(
  //                           loggerCallback ,{
  //                                level: Msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
  //                                piiLoggingEnabled: false,
  //                                correlationId: '1234'
  //                           }
  //                   )
  //   }
};


// define application permissions   
const scopes = ['directory.accessasuser.all', 'directory.readwrite.all', 'group.readwrite.all', 'groupmember.readwrite.all', 'openid', 'profile', 'sites.read.all', 'user.read', 'tasks.readwrite' ]; 


function loggerCallback(logLevel, message, containsPii) {
   console.log(message);
}
```

**auth.js**

```js
const msalApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

if (msalApplication.getAccount()) {
    console.log("you refreshed the page and you are still signed in");
    toggle_sign_in_and_sign_out(); 
}

const loginRequest = {
  scopes: scopes
}

async function sign_in() {
  try {
    await msalApplication.loginPopup(loginRequest);
    console.log('id_token acquired at: ' + new Date().toString());
    var account_info = msalApplication.getAccount(); 
    if (account_info) {
      console.log("sign in success");
      console.log(account_info); 
      show_response("n/a",account_info); 
        toggle_sign_in_and_sign_out(); 
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("sign in error");
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function sign_out() {
    msalApplication.logout();
    toggle_sign_in_and_sign_out(); 
}
```

**graph.js**

```js
const authProviderOptions = new MicrosoftGraph.MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(scopes);
const authProvider = new MicrosoftGraph.ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(msalApplication, authProviderOptions);
const client_options = {
    authProvider
};
const client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.initWithMiddleware(client_options);

async function get_stuff(endpoint) {

    try {

        if (endpoint === "my_details") {
            var path = "/me";
            var response = await client.api(path)
                .get();

        }
        //  there are different handlers here for different api requests 

        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the changes I needed to make:

(*I have one remaining issue where, when I reload the page, the graph requests do not work, the error is*:  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'api')` *- perhaps i need to call* `initializeGraphClient()` *again on page load so that `graphClient` is not `undefined`?...*)

**index.html**

Change reference to MSAL and SDK scripts:

```html
<script src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.16.1/js/msal-browser.min.js" integrity="sha384-bPBovDNeUf0pJstTMwF5tqVhjDS5DZPtI1qFzQI9ooDIAnK8ZCYox9HowDsKvz4i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@3.0.0/lib/graph-js-sdk.js"></script>
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@3.0.0/lib/graph-client-msalBrowserAuthProvider.js"></script>
```

**config.js**

Add the `mailboxsettings.read` scope, so that the new `getUser()` function defined in `graph.js` works.

```js
const scopes = ['directory.accessasuser.all', 'directory.readwrite.all', 'group.readwrite.all', 'groupmember.readwrite.all', 'mailboxsettings.read', 'openid', 'profile', 'sites.read.all', 'tasks.readwrite', 'user.read' ];
```

**auth.js**

Multiple changes - this is the new contents:

```js
const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

if (sessionStorage.getItem("graphUser") !== null) {
  console.log("you refreshed the page and you are still signed in");
  toggle_sign_in_and_sign_out(); 
}

const loginRequest = {
  scopes: scopes
}

async function sign_in() {
  try {
    // use MSAL to login
    const authResult = await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
    console.log('id_token acquired at: ' + new Date().toString());

    // initialize the graph client
    initializeGraphClient(msalInstance, authResult.account, loginRequest.scopes);

    // get the user's profile from Graph
    var user = await getUser();

    // save the profile in session
    sessionStorage.setItem('graphUser', JSON.stringify(user));

    toggle_sign_in_and_sign_out();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function sign_out() {
  sessionStorage.removeItem('graphUser');
  msalInstance.logout();
  toggle_sign_in_and_sign_out();
}
```

**graph.js**

Multiple changes - here is new contents:

```js
let graphClient = undefined;

function initializeGraphClient(msalInstance, account, scopes)
{
  // create an authentication provider
  const authProvider = new MSGraphAuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthProvider
  .AuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthenticationProvider(msalInstance, {
    account: account,
    scopes: scopes,
    interactionType: msal.InteractionType.PopUp
  });

  // initialize the Graph client
  graphClient = MicrosoftGraph.Client.initWithMiddleware({authProvider});
}

console.log("graphClient:");
console.log(graphClient);

async function getUser() {
  return await graphClient
    .api('/me')
    // only get the fields used by the app
    .select('id,displayName,mail,userPrincipalName,mailboxSettings')
    .get();
}

async function get_stuff(endpoint) {  

    console.log("endpoint is:  " + endpoint);

    try {

        if (endpoint === "my_details") {
            var path = "/me";
            var response = await graphClient.api(path)
                .get();

        }
        //  there are different handlers here for different api requests 

        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

**References**

[Migrating from MSAL 1.x to MSAL 2.x](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/v1-migration.md)

Be aware however, that there is *a lot* of documentation out there on the topic of authentication (and the different ways it can be done) and I found it very easy to become lost.

The JavaScript SDK 'automates' some of the manual steps but I had to read the [tutorial code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript) in parallel with the MSAL documentation *very carefully* to see how it all fit together.